Intellij IDEA Debugger is waiting for application to start; debug address: '127.0.0.1:17724', transport: 'socket'
Environment
Intellij IDEA : 2024.1
Tomcat : 9.0.54
SDK : 1.8.0_275
After starting TOMCAT in DEBUG MODE, you can access the portal page of localhost:8080, but the Debugger is waiting for application to start message keeps appearing; debugging address: '127.0.0.1:17724', transmission: 'socket'
And it cannot be stopped after passing the breakpoint
Has anyone encountered this problem?
enter image description here
enter image description here
I tried changing PORT and turning off the firewall
Also try changing VM OPTION
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=40625
But it's useless. It's still show debugger waiting for application start.
BY THE WAY , It’s a GRADLE project
[enter image description here][1][1]: https://i.sstatic.net/TRvxJ.png

Did you check the server logs? Does the server start?

I can see the front-end screen of localhost:8080, but there are some warnings in the server log. I am not sure whether it is related.
24-Apr-2024 01:01:24.814 warn [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule.begin Match [Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context] failed to set property [debug] to [0]

Please contact support at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/requests/new with the full server log and the output in IntelliJ IDEA Run console, share a sample project to reproduce the issue.
